# Parallel boolean and string

Tags: java, android, pojo

I have the next question:

I am doing retrofit request from android device to server and in response it gives me variable `status` with one of three values:

`'status'=>true`

`'status'=>false`

`'status'=>limit`

For server `true` and `false` - this is boolean values, and I am able to handle this values as boolean, but `limit` - this is String type for server and I cannot handle it, because I am waiting only boolean in response.

So the question is: can I handle `limit` value? Or server should change response?

My POJO about `status` looks like:

```
@SerializedName("status")
    @Expose
    private boolean status;

public boolean getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(boolean status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
```

For example, in theory I can create in my POJO smth like:

```
@SerializedName("status2")
    @Expose
    private String status2;

public String getStatus2() {
        return status2;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status2) {
        this.status2 = status2;
    }
```

and when I need to handle `status=>limit`, I will call `getStatus2()` instead of `getStatus()`.

Comment: do you want status to be boolean value or string always?

Comment: You can check your status for the instance by getting status as an `Object`:
   

        if (status instanceof Boolean) {
            //some logic with boolean
        }
        if (status instanceof String) {
            //some logic with String
        }

Comment: both boolean and string... Server gives to me two boolean values and one string value for `status`.

Comment: @Vault23 I will try this, thanks.

Comment: @danyapd let me know if it works or not

Comment: @Vault23, as I understood, I can do this only with Boolean class so I have changed type of status from `boolean` to `Boolean` class and got error on my getStatus(): `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.Boolean.booleanValue()' on a null object reference`. So I can't use Boolean, right?

Comment: why don't you make use of an enum `Status` with possible values `true, false, limit`.

Comment: boolean is a primitive type and there are no instances of boolean, but there are of Boolean class. You need to modify your getStatus() method by returning Object instead of boolean or String. so it should be like this: public Object getStatus() {};

Comment: @Vault23 you were right - everything works now.

Comment: @danyapd great!